# Illustrator: Converting a letterhead design to Word

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, automation, image-format, microsoft-word

I created this letterhead for a client in Illustrator and it got approved. It now needs to get converted to a Word document for internal usage. What's the best way to make this conversion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Save images as PNG files. Insert them into Word as a Header and/or footer. Save the Word file as a template.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With regards to headers and footers. Is it possible to add in a "side" header/ footer. In my case the letterhead is not at the top or bottom of the page, but on the left hand side.. (I know this is more a word question now..)

Comment: You can add a background image (again use PNG) to the page.

Comment: Don't forget to test the colours in print (can't use CMYK but you'll still need to be sure your colours do come out right - especially any vivid reds, blues, greens), and to export the PNG large enough for the intended PPI. 300 pixels per inch is typical for print, so you'll typically export your PNG with a pixel height and width equal to 300 times the height and width in pixels it covers on the page. Doesn't have to be exact, just has to be high enough to show no pixelation or scuzziness when printed.

Comment: @user568458 you'd also have to consider the file size of the final template, because if the graphic is large and detailed it may make the file size larger than necessary/convenient (for emails mostly).

Comment: **Just a comment on the WMF format**... yes Microsoft *wants* you to use it... but it's **not** reliable in any way, shape, or form when used for inserted graphics in a Microsoft application document which will *not* reside on *only* your system. As soon as the document moves to another computer the WNF format can be a problem. PNG will work everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create design (text and image)
2. Save as WMF.
3. Open word -
4. Insert picture (insert the wmf file)
5. Right click and choose Edit picture.
6. When the dialog box appears to change the file do editable doc, choose Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a signage template in Word using a full (11 x 8-1/2 in) page 300 ppi png image as a header, scaled to 100% and mechanically oriented (advanced image formatting) to 0/0 horz/vert alignment. Final file size of the Word template file is 133 KB. Allows graphic formatting of the entire page while maintaining margin control for the overlying text. Be sure to set text wrap for the graphic to "behind text".

Answer (score 1):

If you want letter head design in illustrator quality. Then export your design in windows metafile format (.wmf).

now you can add .wmf format in word document by inserting picture and align properly as your requirement.

I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Saving my Illustrator file as PDF and then inserting it as a watermark in Word at 100% without Washout worked for me without it being blurry.

Comment: Inserting PDFs in Word is a mess. I do not recommend it. Transparency gets all kinds of screwed up, and vectors get needlessly rasterised at seemingly random resolutions that you can’t even control.