# Convert my Illustrator file-letterhead into word doc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, export

I created this letterhead design in Illustrator and I have to give it to the client now, as a usable file in Microsoft Word... I don't really know Microsoft Word, so I need a step by step detailed clarification if it is possible!!!

Comment: Next time: Design in Word, other than the logo. Don't even boot anything in the Adobe suite. It will save you a lot of heartache. If you design in IL/ID, the client wants *that*, and quite often Word can't reproduce *that*, and then everyone is disappointed. Begin as you mean to go on, and it's much easier to manage expectations.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the WMF format. This format supports vectors and is devloped by Microsoft. Besides MS Office it's not very useful, but the only possibility in MS Office to use vector-shapes form other software like illustrator.

Comment: You could also use eps but that looks ugly on screen

Comment: This works for the newer versions of Word. For older ones (2010 and older) there are a lot of issues when placing a EPS-file if possible at all.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site.

In answer to your question.

> Save images as PNG files. Insert them into Word as a Header and/or
>   footer. Save the Word file as a template.

[See here for similar question.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25188/converting-an-illustrator-letter-head-design-to-word)

Comment: Let's say I made it! I inserted the png file in word successfully! Now the problem is that my original design has both header and footer...is it possible to remove only the header from second page of the word doc?

Comment: Or do i have to create 2 design files first, one with the header and another with the footer, and then insert them separately in word?? do you know what i mean? i hope i didn't confuse you..

Comment: I think, I know what you mean. Best way to do it, save a header and a footer in two different .png's. Open your document and insert them into the header and footer areas. Save as template. -- Sorry if this is over complicating it.

Comment: No it's ok, i think i made it! :) THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: Perfect. If this Answer was correct then could you mark it please. Thank you.