# Illustrator: Any way to convert letterhead/sheet design to Word?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, branding, microsoft-word

I'm not sure if the question is clear, I'll try to explain.

This client asked for some branding sort of work which includes, on top of regular header/footer letterheads, some files with fields which will be filled.

The client is in the nutritionist field and she was looking to make her clients files more interesting looking.

I worked in Illustrator and I am not sure how I can make files which contain fields she can fill in a Word Document (client clearly won't use Illustrator to edit files). She has also told me she intends to print out these files and fill them out manually too.

Even if I exported the Ai files as images and placed them as backgrounds within Word, I don't think that is the most effective way. Placing text boxes over the fields that need to be filled sounds messy and I feel that on transfer from computer to computer they could get all messed up.

I don't even know if what I'm trying to do is possible (at least to my level of skill or with the software we're limited to), so I'm considering telling her I won't be able to do the editable files, but maybe there's a way I'm not aware of.

Comment: Possible duplicate or helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25188/illustrator-converting-a-letterhead-design-to-word -- In my personal experience, A PDF with common fonts between you two.. then she can use Adobe Acrobat to edit to an extent. Word is **always** a nightmare.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illustrator: Converting a letterhead design to Word](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25188/illustrator-converting-a-letterhead-design-to-word)

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution but it is not practical. but can be convert illustrator files to word format.

1. Firstly open AI file what you want.
   note: PDF and other formats also can be open
2. Then open new page from Microsoft word.
   note:you want size/ margin etc.
3. And then you can be copy separately top and bottom section from AI file.
4. Finlay you can be paste separately top and bottom section to word file.

Thank you
Lahiru K

Answer (score 0):

Scrap what you did and do it in Word. Note even that you need to do it with the same version of word the client is using. The sad fact is that Microsoft Office does not allow you to do a good work otherwise/even then.

The safest way to export graphics to word is one of:

- Making it a PNG, this is essentially wat Microsoft wants you to do.
- Copy pasting the vectors to PowerPoint on a Windows machine. Then a important step is to ungroup the graphic, this will turn it PowerPoint native. aYou can now copyto Word. This is not without problems so watch out for changes as they crop up.

Other methods include:

- Using WMF files as between. This is essentially a Inferior way to the PowerPoint method. Where you dont have any way to deal with problems as they arise. They are also somewhat fragile when moving form OS to OS.
- Putting PDF in word. This works if you can control how the client operates the software. There is a **risk** that at any point form here to future word decides to rasterize the image (it does this periodically). So unless you want a call from client randomly in future avoid this.
- Putting in EPS files. This works but you must enable a plugin that's been disabled. This has the same rasterization problem, although it only triggers in image rotation and scale. This is essentially the only way to inject CMYK into word. It however only works if you print directly form word to a PostScipt printer or via Distiller (no words own PDF export wont do). Most likely your client will say just too hard.

* Yes you get better results if you go via PowerPoint

Comment: Actually I've had luck with placing logos as SVG files in Word which stayed vector sharp. PDFs on the other hand became rasterized and blurry. But this might depend on the version of Word used. (Working in Word feels like trying to build a house of cards with your hands wrapped in bandages dipped in glue.)

Comment: @Wolff yes ive herad that but i haven't gotten it to work. Word is a bit dangerous in that it might or might not work forever, so the PDF does work even vector sharp, if you dont do anything ever in word. Only its own internal form will not break randomly. The way you can see this is that you can ungroup the graphic and manipulate the handles does SVG do this?

Comment: You can just use *Insert > Pictures* and choose the SVG. It's inserted as a "locked" object, but you can right-click it and choose *Group > Ungroup* to convert it to a *Microsoft Office drawing object* and then each element is editable. I have no idea how "safe" this method is.